# returning to upgrade from remove details list

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I am stuck.  I am upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10.  It told me 89 items would be removed with my permission.  It gave me the option to see details.  I took it and got a scrollable list of the 89 items.  How do I get out of the list in my terminal and complete the upgrade?

Comment: What command have you used to upgrade to 14.10?

Comment: do-release-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be esc , q ,or tab  one of the 3 ,,,,,,but it has been a wile sense I did a upgrade with do-release-upgrade .
I keep 4 partitions for going from one release to the next and just do a clean install over the oldest except for the LTS release which gets it on the release of the next LTS